# SKPhysicsContact is there any way to determine which body is A and B?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

in SpriteKit we detect the in the didBeginContact method.
but this looks a bit stupid to do something like that:
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

```
    if let contactA = contact.bodyA.node?.name {

        if let contactB = contact.bodyB.node?.name {

            //now that we have safely unwrapped these nodes, we can operate on them

            if contactA == "ball" {

                collisionBetweenBall(contact.bodyA.node!, object: contact.bodyB.node!)

            } else if contactB == "ball" {

                collisionBetweenBall(contact.bodyB.node!, object: contact.bodyA.node!)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

is there any way I can ensure that bodyA is always a ball? is there any rules related to categorybitmask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using simple categories, with each physics body belonging to only one category, then this alternative form of didBeginContact may be more readable:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

switch contactMask {

   case categoryBitMask.ball | categoryBitMask.something:
       print("Collision between ball and something")
       let ballNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == categoryBitMask.ball ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
       ballNode.pop()
       score += 10

   default :
       //Some other contact has occurred
       print("Some other contact")
   }
}
```

Note that if your categories are more complicated, this won't work as the simple AND tests (`categoryBitMask.ball | categoryBitMask.something`) won't match.

Comment: In the situation where multiple contacts occur at the same time, this code can crash in some cases. Let say you have three objects intersecting. SpriteKit can process only one contact at time. And say that you are removing object (of type) A from a parent when it is contacting with object of type B or C. So didBeginContact will be called twice. And if you remove object A from its parent, in the next didBeginContact call, forced unwrapping will fail. You should point him not to use forced unwrapping like this, because node property might be nil ... Otherwise, it should work and it's readable :)

Comment: @Whirlwind does this mean `if let` and `guard` are useful here?

Comment: @Confused Most likey if let or a guard yeah. Or even optional chaining. Just to prevent a potential crash. Which may occur...

Comment: I've been (recently) starting to see the light of day on how and why to use `if let`, haven't got around to figuring out `guard` yet. But I love playing with physics engines, so this looks like a good excuse to find out how to do it in a sensible location, with purpose. Thank you!!!

Comment: I deeply studied the SKTemplate's use of `if let` to `copy()` `SKShapeNodes`. It was a insightful moment when I realised it was really doing two things. 1. converting an optional to an actual of the same name, and 2. providing a chance to do a bunch of things inside a scope. I'm still out to lunch on the benefits of closing something inside that scope, as would happen in this answer from Steve, where I'd put an `if let` for the ballNode assignment, which would then wrap the pop() call and addition to the score variable. Is this the right place/idea use of `if let` in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do this

First you would store your bit mask categories if you are not doing it already.

```
enum PhysicsCategory {
     static let ball: UInt32 =  0x1 << 0
     static let wall: UInt32 =  0x1 << 1
     static let enemy: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}
```

and than assign them like so to your sprites

```
 ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball
 ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.wall | PhysicsCategory.enemy

 wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.wall
 wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0 

 enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy
 enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
```

Note: Because ball checks for contacts with both wall and enemy in this example you would not need to tell wall or enemy to check contacts with ball. 
Its fine to do it on 1 physics body so you can set it to 0 on the others unless they have other specific contacts to look for.

Than you can check for them in the contact method like so without the double if statements.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }


    // Ball hit wall or wall hit ball
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.ball) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.wall) {

          // Some code
    }

    // Ball hit enemy or enemy hit ball
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.ball) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) {

          // Some code
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to set the delegate in didMoveToView of your scene for this to work.

```
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Hope this helps