# SKScene - How to Get Class from SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm using spritekit to create a scene. I have 3 classes: GameScene, Bullet, and Enemy. In my GameScene I'm added create SKSpriteNode via my Bullet and Enemy classes.

```
var newBullet = Bullet(); 
newBullet.CreateBullet()
self.addChild(newBullet.GetSpriteNode())
```

Later on I'm using collision detection by extending the SKPhysicsContactDelegate.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("collision detected!")
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode;
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode;

    //here's where I'd like to call bullet.hit() 
    //var bullet = firstBody.GetClass(Bullet)
    //bullet.hit()
    // I tried -  let tempBullet = ((firstBody as? Bullet));
    //but firstBody as? Bullet returns nil
    //print(firstBody) - it indeed is my bullet sprite... why is it nil?
}
```

I wrote my pseudo code above... how would I get the class associated with the SKSpriteNode..? Is there any way to have my class script be part of the SKSpriteNode and if so - how do I get the script attached to call it's functions?

Also here's my bullet class

```
class Bullet : SKSpriteNode{
   var skNode : SKSpriteNode?

   func CreateBullet(){
        skNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 2, height: 10))
        skNode?.name = "bullet"
        skNode?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        skNode?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: skNode!.size)

        skNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true;
        skNode?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false;
        skNode?.physicsBody?.pinned = false;
        skNode?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;

        skNode?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet;
        skNode?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy;
        skNode?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy;
    }

    func GetSKNode() -> SKNode{
        return skNode!;
    }
}
```

Comment: try casting the first body as a bullet type

Comment: Just tried- let tempBullet = ((firstBody as? Bullet));  it compiles, but prints nil...

Comment: make you bullet class of type SKSpriteNode, then by casted hopefully it wont print nil

Comment: I'm doing so... class Bullet : SKSpriteNode{} but it is still nil... Is the way I'm adding it correct... self.addChild()... will add that func into the question too for reference

Comment: just added a little more code/detail for reference @SanadBarjawi

Comment: you're passing SKPhysicsContact as an argument in the func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact),

Comment: thats correct... but (contact.bodyA.node as? Bullet) returns nil...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206534/discussion-between-robbie-and-sanad-barjawi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are creating the bullet the way you do. I think it should look more along the lines of. When subclassing a SKSpriteNode, you should override the initializer to add you own custom setup.

```
class Bullet: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {
        let size = CGSize(width: 2, height: 10)
        super.init(texture: nil, color: .white, size: size)
        self.name = "bullet"
        self._setupBody(size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //Prefix private methods with an underscore
    private func _setupBody(size: CGSize) {
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
        self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.physicsBody?.pinned = false
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    }

}
```

The reason it's nil when you try to cast as a Bullet is you are creating a SKSpriteNode when calling `newBullet.CreateBullet()` instead of an instance of 
the Bullet class.

Lastly in a physicsContact there are two bodies in a contact. We don't know which one is the enemy and which one is the bullet. So we can write code for both cases, although if you are checking more collisions there are better ways such as this answer: [Determining Contact Bodies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436379/6738247)

```
class BulletScene:SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        //Case #1: Bullet = bodyA and Enemy = bodyB
        if let bullet = contact.bodyA.node as? Bullet, let enemy = contact.bodyB as? Enemy {
            print("Bullet was BodyA!")
        //Case #2: Bullet = bodyB and Enemy = bodyA
        }else if let enemy = contact.bodyA as? Enemy, let bullet = contact.bodyB.node as? Bullet {
            print("Bullet was BodyB!")
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing SKSpriteNode is totally fine and the recommended way.
Anyway, if you made for any reason a different design choice to keep SKNode set apart from its handler, you can use the SKNode userData, intended to support game logic without subclassing the node.
So a generic solution can be the following one (I'm new to Swift, maybe the code could be written better).
Once for all, copy this code in your project:

```
protocol SKNodeHandler: class { }
extension SKNode {
    var handler : SKNodeHandler {
        set {
            if self.userData == nil {
                self.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
            }
            self.userData![0xFF] = NSValue.init(nonretainedObject: newValue)
        }
        get {
            let nsValue = self.userData![0xFF] as? NSValue
            return (nsValue?.nonretainedObjectValue as! SKNodeHandler)
        }
    }
}
```

Your Bullet class is

```
class Bullet : SKNodeHandler {
   var skNode : SKSpriteNode?

   func CreateBullet() {
       skNode = SKSpriteNode(/* ... */)
       skNode.handler = self
   }
   /* ... */
   
   func hit() {
       skNode.run( /* ... */ )
   }

}
```

And in the contact detection:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //You identified bodyA is the Bullet node (by its category bit mask or its node name)
    let bullet = contact.bodyA.node.handler as? Bullet
    bullet?.hit()

}
```